# ngModel - TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: arrays, angular, angular-ngmodel

I have this json that shows my levels of data (something is regular, something is array as you can see.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I keep getting this error:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

I believe there is something in this [(ngModel)] path that I seems to get wrong (perhaps array of addresses or something) because **context.company** works fine for first 4 (name,code,endpoint and email). [![enter image description here][3]][3]

Also, here is modal through which I link inputs to this "company" table in database:[![enter image description here][4]][4]

If someone can show me solution, because I got in dead end. Thanks

Comment: `addresses` is an **array**.  you'll either need to loop through the array using `*ngFor` or specifically target the first element (`addresses[0]`).

Comment: @Claies But, then I have error, and now it's Cannot read property 'city' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `addresses is an array, you can use 'addresses[0].city.name'.

Comment: Yes, but now I have different Error...now it's: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined

Comment: see here https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator